# css clip masking for parallax effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to clip mask an image to its background so it won't be overlapping but not sure how to do it. I tried background-clip box/padding and it didn't work.

I tried using clip: rect(); its not doing anything unless I'm doing it wrong.

https://jsfiddle.net/LxgcLggq/

```
 <div class="paralax">
        <div class="fast"></div>
        <div class="medium"></div>
        <div class="slow"></div>
    </div>

.paralax{
width: 100%;
height: 306px;
background: #ccc;
position: relative;
display: block;
clear: both;
}

.fast{
    background: url(http://s13.postimg.org/v7rm6cidj/fast.png);
    width: 100%;
    height: 193px;
}
.medium{
    background: url(http://s7.postimg.org/ae6yxfd4b/medium.png);
    width: 100%;
    height: 510px;
    clip: rect(0px, 0px, 100px, 0px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `absolute` or `fixed` positioning on the object, and then expand the left (second position) of rect like so:

```css
.parallax {
  width: 100%;
  height: 306px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.medium {
  background: url(http://s7.postimg.org/ae6yxfd4b/medium.png);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 510px;
  clip: rect(0px, 1025px, 100px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax">
  <div class="medium"></div>
</div>
```

Note: that `clip` is deprecated (but still works in many browsers), while `clip-path` its replacement may not work in all browsers.

Also, to specify `rect` parameters: they are distances from Top-Left corner, but values are specified in Top, Right, Bottom, Left order. Not very intuitive, and there are several websites that fail to document this correctly.